# Cassandra Database overwhelmed?

Tags: cassandra

I created a table in a cassandra database with the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE table(
  num int,
  part_key int,
  val1 int,
  val2 float,
  val3 text,
  ...,
  PRIMARY KEY((part_key),num)
);
```

The table stores data from a technical device. The partitioning key part_key is 1 for the every record, because I want to execute range queries on only one server. I know this is a bad use case for Cassandra, but I need to do this for a comparison.

The primary key num is the number of the record (from 1 to 8.000.000).

There are like 400 other values per record that are float, int and text type. I Inserted 8.000.000 records to this table (43 GB) and wanted to run my queries like:

```
SELECT num, val1, val45, val90 
FROM ks.table 
WHERE part_key=1 AND num>9999 AND num<20001;
```

I executed the query in the cql-shell and got "operation timed out". So I changed read_request_timeout_in_ms and range_request_timeout_in_ms in the cassandra.yaml file to 60000 (2 minutes).

When executing the query again I got "Error 10054: the existing connection was closed by the remotehost" after 5 minutes. The Datastax Cassandra Community Server 2.0.11 Service was not running anymore on the server.

I restarted the service, tried it again and the service crashed again. I could not even restart the service and I had to restart the server. 
I also tried this using the Cassandra cpp-driver and also could not execute this query.

Small queries like

```
... AND num<1000;
```

are still possible.

My question is: did I do something wrong? I know Cassandra is better with more nodes but I thought that Cassandra would only need some more time. Is it possible, that Cassandra is unable to execute a query like that?

Thank You!

The server:

Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5504 @ 2.00GHz 2.00GHz (2 processors) / 16GB RAM

CPU utilization: 50% - 60% and after 15 seconds around 30% / RAM: 2,9 GB the whole time

EDIT:

My Cassandra keyspace is now 60GB and small queries like

```
... AND num<10;
```

and even the Inserts return time out. Sometimes the service crashes... 
Please can someone who got an idea explain that? One answer said that a node with 43GB is not the same in a cluster with more nodes as in my cluster with only one node. Can somebody explain this?

Thank You!

Comment: The server specs are important. Check if your server is running out of memory /processor time. Any way a full stack trace will hep a lot.

Comment: I added the server information in my post. Where should I do a stack trace, if I use the cql shell? Should I run the query in c++ and do a stack trace?

Comment: This could be due to a host of things. Based on some simple (and perhaps inaccurate) caclulations in my head, you're requesting ~50 MBs of data from Cassandra in your range query. Depending on your location and distance from your server, that could be causing your timeout (just a guess). Would it be possible for you to batch your queries to 1000 items at a time (instead of the current 10,000 item query) and time them and post the results? Do them in a sequential for loop and record the time it takes to retrieve the results.

Comment: Yes! That's possible and I think that's a good way to resolve this issue. The queries are still very slow, but now they are possible. One query that searches 1000 records still takes 1,5s... That's not what I expected, because when I query 1000000 records that takes a little bit to much time, but I guess that's because I got only one server. Hypothetical question: How many servers do you think are needed to set up a database like this (43GB)?

Answer (score 3):

One of the key issues here is that cqlsh with the version of C* that you are running does not page through results. This means the entire result-set has to be serialized at the time of the query which given your data model will be quite large(as pointed out by kha). I would try performing similar queries using a paging enabled driver and of course make sure that you have sufficient network bandwith for returning the data.

43GB Should be easily handled by a single C* node, although operating a C* cluster with only a single node sacrifices almost all of the benefits that C* offers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you explain to me why it's different to use a cluster with only one node and one node in a cluster with more nodes? Right now I am doing what kha suggested. I run more queries for only 1000 items. That's still slow, but a paging enabled driver would not help me there, right? I would really like to hear your answer! @RussS

Comment: With a single node you have a single point of failure and if no replicas exist you will be extremely susceptible to GC pauses. I would definitely recommend using a RDBMS if only need a single machine.

The paging drivers will stop C* from pulling in too much data at a time on the server side and are better suited for reading in extremely long rows. This may assist you with server side GC and the time required to pull in rows as they will keep track of where they are in a particular row and make iteration cheaper.

Comment: Interesting! can you please provide more info in regards to: "cqlsh with the version of C* that you are running does not page through results" ? According to: https://github.com/datastax/java-driver paging is supported for versions >= 2.0

Comment: In C* < 2.1 Cqlsh uses an old python driver which doesn't page. C* supports paging but that particular tool does not.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was using cqlsh 4.1.1 with Cassandra 2.0.11 and also the beta c++ driver 1.0. Do you know whether they support paging or not? I understood that with one server I am susceptible to GC pauses, but how long can they be that a timeout (1-2min) exists? Also I get timeout and service crashes with Insert queries... Does somebody have got an idea for this issue(I explained it in my post edit)? @alfasin

Comment: Please, does somebody know why the Cassandra service crashes? Right now I don't need more suggestions on this topic, but I really need to explain what happened... I already know about GC-pauses and paging, but I don't think that are the reasons. The question in my edit is still not clear. I am thankful for your previous help, but I need to now what happens.